# HTML submit button shadow border issue

Tags: html, css

```
input[type=submit] {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 30px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin-left: 34.998721%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 0px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(0, 154, 222);
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

So when I apply this styles to the `<p>` tag it looks:

[image]

but when I apply it for submit button it looks with some borders around it:

How to remove this border?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding this property to the css rule:

```
border: none;
```

if it didn't work then also add:

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: yea perfect, birder works for me, sorry I am not web developer, so just faced with this small issue. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following for the active state:

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since button elements do have a border on it's own, you have to disable it in order to get get it not shown.

To achieve this, you can rely on the border-style option found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

So if you want to disable the standard-border of your submit button, you can simply add this line to your CSS.

```
border-style: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

border-style property is set to be none by default, it seems that by defining border-top-left-radius property and so on the border-style is alternated to be solid thus you have the unwanted border. You can simply add border-color property and set it as transparent, then you should have got your desired result